# Is this a subdomain domain that work with CDNs?

Tags: cdn, subdomain

Since browsers have a connection limit per host we are using multiple subdomains to serve files. However I wanted to check if we could modify the subdomain a bit and still get the same results.

for ex:  currently using files01.domain.com, files02.domain.com, files03.domain.com,  can we use file01.assets.domain.com, file03.assets.domain.com, file03.assets.domain.com and still get past the browser connection limits?

Or will the browser detect assets.domain.com as the master host and limit connections to all the sub-hosts under it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should work fine.

The connection limits are per server not per subdomain.  From [RFC2616](http://rfc.askapache.com/rfc2616/rfc2616.html#section-8):

> Clients that use persistent connections SHOULD limit the number of
>      simultaneous connections that they maintain to a given **server**. A
>      single-user client SHOULD NOT maintain more than 2 connections with
>      any server or proxy.